# black screen on launch, both 20.04 and 22.04 amd rx5700tx? dualboot with windows 10

Tags: drivers, dual-boot, kernel, amd-graphics

i'm trying to install ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS but it freezes in boot screen with message
`/dev/sda7: clean, 19126/2493680 files, 2116933/9963008 blocks` (on kernel 5.15.0-56)

tried looking at the bootlog from the freeze but cant make sense what going on
https://pastebin.com/RVDjvWD5

windows 10

gpu: rx5700xt

cpu ryzen 5 2600

mobo x470 aorus

first time i reinstalling after the 20.04, it didn't work but going safe-mode and doing `sudo apt-get update` and `upgrade` restart and it able to load normally.
after messing around trying to get rocm i somehow broke it(freeze on restart) i've tried to reinstalled ubuntu to start fresh, this time following the same steps as before didn't solve it(black screen or stuck on mobo screen can't remember exactly).

i've had similar issues trying to ubuntu 20.04 and i can't seem to understand what is happening, is it usererror, hardware, amd drivers, kernels, ubuntu mix of some?

the reinstall process is i just delete the ubuntu partition using minitool partition wizard(leave it raw), launch the usb which i've used rufus to install the ubuntu image on, manually(not install along side windows) choose the free 40gigs to be formatted to ext4, / as root, and the most minimal installation there is.

Comment: " Error, this is a private paste or is pending moderation. If this paste belongs to you, please login to Pastebin to view it. "

Comment: ty, i've changed it and hopefully it updates quick.
also in grub, first option 'ubuntu' does it launch newest or oldest kernel?
22.04 comes with 56, and 43(which work), right now i wanted to launch 56 safe-mode to test something, but accidentally clicked regular 56(out of the advanced menu) and it worked. i assumed the 'ubuntu' in grub launches top most\newest kernel if multiple are present

Comment: The latest kernel version is normally the default one.

Comment: i've tried a bunch of times to see that the main button results in a freeze and that the advanced options one boots normally and it was consistent. 
after getting consisted boot result i've installed pip `sudo apt install pip` restarted and now the 56 kernel freezes on boot too

Comment: realized the previous command is bad and wrong, reinstalled ubuntu, updated, did the right command `sudo apt install python3-pip` and boot freezes again